# Retrofit annotation with same url prefix?

Tags: android, retrofit2

In my android app I use Retrofit like this:

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
public interface TangoRestClient {

    @POST("/myproject/1/user/login")
    Call<JsonElement> login(@Body JsonElement body);

    @POST("/myproject/1/user/register")
    Call<JsonElement> register(@Body JsonElement body);

    @POST("/myproject/1/user/dictionary")
    Call<JsonElement> getDictionary(@Body JsonElement body);

}
```

as you can see all methods has same url prefix:

```
/myproject/1/user
```

it it possible to extract this constant and do smt like this :

```
String prefix = " /myproject/1/user";

@POST("{prefix}/login")
Call<JsonElement> login(@Body JsonElement body);

@POST("{prefix}/register")
Call<JsonElement> register(@Body JsonElement body);

@POST("{prefix}/dictionary")
Call<JsonElement> getDictionary(@Body JsonElement body);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that I do this is to create an `interface` and a managing class, which looks something like this:

```
public class CatalogManager extends NetworkingManager {
    private String id;

    public CatalogManager(String baseUrl) {
        super(baseUrl);
    }

    public CatalogManager(String baseUrl, String id) {
        super(baseUrl);
        this.id = id;
    }

    public interface CatalogInterface {
        @GET("endpoint1")
        Call<Data> getCatalogGenres();

        @GET("endpoint2")
        Call<Data> getGenreMovies(@Query("query_param") String id);
    }

    public void getCatalog(CatalogCallback callback){
        CatalogInterface ci = retrofit.create(CatalogInterface.class);
        Call call = ci.getEndpoint1();
        call.enqueue(callback);
    }

    public void getCatalogCatagories(CatalogGenreCallback callback){
        CatalogInterface ci = retrofit.create(CatalogInterface.class);
        Call call = ci.getEndpoint2(id);
        call.enqueue(callback);
    }

    @Override
    protected OkHttpClient getHttpClient() {
        return super.getHttpClient();
    }

    @Override
    protected Gson getGson() {
        return super.getGson();
    }
}
```

Then when I call the method, I do:

```
CatalogManager cm = new CatalogManager(Constants.BASE_URL , getId());
                cm.getEndpoint1(new CatalogGenreCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Data> call, Response<SliderData> response) {

                        Data data =  response.body();
                        if (data != null) {
                            adapter.updateAdapterInfo(data);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Data> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + t.toString());
                    }

                });
```

Where I have `Constant.BASE_URL`, you can pass in whatever URL you like. In your case, you might create a constant that has your base plus your common path:

```
    CatalogManager cm = new CatalogManager(Constant.BASE_URL + Constant.COMMONT_PATH , getId());
```